# Including a separate binary into an ELF executable

Tags: makefile, linker, osdev, objcopy

I am developing an operating system. I would like to include a small `asm` program into my main kernel `elf` that can serve as the first process to load. I am having trouble getting this to work. The program is `initcode.s`. I using the following `Makefile` which I modified from the xv6 operating system source for this task:

```
initcode:
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) initcode.s -o initcode.o
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -N -e start -Ttext 0 -o initcode initcode.o
    objcopy --input binary --output elf32-i386 --binary-architecture i386 initcode.out initcode


kernel.elf: $(OBJECTS) initcode
    ld -T link.ld -melf_i386 $(OBJECTS) -o kernel.elf initcode
```

The kernel compiles and links fine. `objcopy` also creates markers which enable me to find the binary from within the kernel code. However the contents of `initcode` is trashed. The contents does not resemble what the assembler step produced within `initcode.out`.

How can I achieve including `initcode.s` as a separate binary somewhere in my main `kernel.elf` with some markers generated so I can find it from within my kernel? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 simple methods. There are certainly more complex methods if you prefer.

1. Write a small utility to convert the initcode binary to an asm file (or even C file) containing a GAS data section. Then assemble that file and link it with your kernel. Your initcode will than appear as a variable in your kernel.

OR

2. Simply 'cat' the initcode binary to the end of your kernel elf after the link step. This method will depend on whether your loader is happy to support this.